# How do I style this jQuery mobile TextInput

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I just need a little help after several attempts that haven't worked. How do I style the default TextInput in jQuery on mobile like the TextInput in the image I have attached below?

[image: Here's [the textinput image](http://www.71slabsolution.com/img/imgtextinput.jpg)]

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are just starting on design and English , you can customize your CSS that way or you can use some other UI plugins like twitter bootstrap , if i am not wrong twitter bootstrap provides one just like that.
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Comment: sorry for my bad english is there any tutorial or links